# Heroku app.json set default django admin password

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-1.8

I'm trying to add a [depoly to heroku button](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-button#creating-the-app-json-file) and I followed their examples and all and ended up with the following app.json for my django app

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "description": "foo website",
  "repository": "https://github.com/foo/bar",
  "keywords": ["python", "django", "foobar"],
  "env": {
    "DJANGO_SECRET_KEY": {
      "description": "A randomly generated secret to secure your Django installation",
      "generator": "secret"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postdeploy": "sh -c 'python manage.py syncdb --noinput; python manage.py migrate --noinput'"
  }
}
```

Doing the `syncdb` will create the auth tables and so on, but what I need is to allow the user who wants to deploy the app to specify the default admin username and password. I realize that doing `heroku run python manage.py syncdb` will prompt the user if we wants to create a superuser, but that's not exactly what I need. I need it to be configured from Heroku's dashboard when a user clicks on the button. I want this to allow non technical people to still be able to deploy the app without going through the terminal and all. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I managed to do what I wanted and thought I'd share it. I was able to do it using `django-extensions`. I made a python script

```
# create_admin.py
import os
if "ADMIN_USER" in os.environ and "ADMIN_PASSWORD" in os.environ:
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    user=User.objects.create_user(os.environ['ADMIN_USER'], password=os.environ['ADMIN_PASSWORD'])
    user.is_superuser=True
    user.is_staff=True
    user.save()
```

and changed the scripts part of my `app.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    "postdeploy": "sh -c 'python manage.py syncdb --noinput; python manage.py migrate --noinput; python manage.py runscript create_admin'"
  }
```

make sure you read `django-extensions` docs for more information on where to place the scripts and how to `python manage.py runscript`.

IMPORTANT: you may want to go to herkou's configs page and remove the environment variables after you run the script.